# On a sufficient condition for the convergence of the Newton-Raphson method

Tags: newton-raphson

Given a suitable function $f$, often of class $C^2$, in the section of quadratic convergence for Newton's iterative method mentioned in [WikipediA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton%27s_iterative_method) I found the following estimate
$$
\displaystyle \left|{\varepsilon _{n+1}}\right|={\frac {\left|f''(\xi _{n})\right|}{2\left|f'(x_{n})\right|}} |\varepsilon _{n}|^2. \tag{6}
$$
where $\alpha$ is a zero of $f$ over the interval $I$ and
$$\varepsilon _{n+1} = \alpha - x_{n+1}.$$
Then, it says that the above estimate (6) can be expressed in the following way:
$$
\displaystyle \left|{\varepsilon _{n+1}}\right|\leq M |\varepsilon _{n}|^2
$$
where $M$ is the supremum of the variable coefficient of $\varepsilon_n^2$, that is:
$$
\displaystyle M=\sup _{x\in I}{\frac {1}{2}}\left|{\frac {f''(x)}{f'(x)}}\right|.
$$
Given this new estimate, it is now clear that the order of convergence is at least quadratic if $x_0$ is chosen suitable and
$$M |\varepsilon_0| < 1.$$
My question is how to prove that the above new inequality is sufficient? The apparent difficulty is to handle the two points $\xi_n$ and $x_n$ in (6).

In various references, the following inequality
$$\varepsilon_{n+1} \leq \frac 12 \frac{\sup_I|f''|}{\inf_I |f'|} |\varepsilon_n|^2$$
often appears. Having this, it is now quite obvious to get the the order of convergence by seeing (6).